# Excel count number of times a column cell value equals

Tags: excel

Hi I have the following spread sheet:

[image]

I want to count the number of times the cells in column C have a value below .8 and where the corresponding cell in column A equals 1. I also want to count the number of times that the cells in column D have a value below .8 and where the corresponding cell in column B is 1?

At the moment I have managed to colour the cells in red when these are true using conditional formatting. But unable to workout how to count these also?

Many thank for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [COUNTIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842):

For Column C:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A10,1,C1:C10,"<" & .8)
```

For Column D:

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B10,1,D1:D10,"<" & .8)
```